# Linear Independence of Matrices with Powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, independence

I can't seem to figure this out, could someone explain the properties of linear independence when it comes to a matrix to the power of something. The question I'm having trouble with is:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a non zero vector. Assume that $x$ is an element of $\operatorname{null}(A^{3})$ but $x$ is not an element of $\operatorname{null}(A^{2})$. Show that the set $\{x,Ax, A^{2}x\}$ is linearly independent.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: suppose it is false, and multiply by $A^2$ first, and then by $A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ ax + bAx + cA^2x = 0. $$

We need to show that $a = b = c = 0$. Apply $A$ to the equation above to get

$$ 0 = A(ax + bAx + cA^2x) = aAx + bA^2x + cA^3x = aAx + bA^2x. $$

Apply $A$ again to get

$$ 0 = A(aAx + bA^2x) = aA^2x + bA^3x = aA^2x. $$

Since $A^2x \neq 0$, we must have $a = 0$. If you return to the previous equation, you'll see that this implies that $b = 0$ and if you return now to the original equation you'll see that $c = 0$.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thank you!